# Trying to make a dynamic PHP link go to another page using Javascript onClick

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a drop down menu that populates dynamically using a php function.  the return string is as follows:

```
    $return_string .= "<li class='dropdown-item-row row' style='" . $style . "' onClick='window.location.href='" . $row['link'] . "'>
                        <span class='dd-pic'>
                            <img src='" . $user_data['profile_pic'] . "'>
                        </span>
                        <span class='dd-right'>
                            <span class='dd-date'>
                                        " . $time_message . "
                            </span>
                            <span class='dd-notif-text'>" . $row['message'] . "</span>
                        </span>
                      </li>";
```

When the user clicks on the link it will take them to the specific notification.  I have on the `<li>` tag `onClick='window.location.href='" . $row['link'] . "'`  The error I'm getting here is Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input.  Can anyone see something that I'm missing here?

It works locally if I wrap it in an `<a>` tag, but this is silly given it's around an `<li>` tag and will likely not work on remote server.  I thought something simple in JS like this might be the solution.

Any help appreciated!  Thanks is advance.

Comment: What's the content of `$row['link']`?

Comment: post.php?id= some number

Comment: You have an error in quotes. Escape them with \... like onClick='window.location.href=\'" . $row['link'] . "\''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside double quotes "$var" simple variables don't need to be concatenated. This should work:

```
$return_string .= "<li class='dropdown-item-row row' 
 style='$style' 
 onClick=\"javascript:window.location.href='" . $row['link'] . "';\">

 <span class='dd-pic'>
 <img src='" . $user_data['profile_pic'] . "'>
 </span>
 <span class='dd-right'>
  <span class='dd-date'>$time_message</span>
  <span class='dd-notif-text'>" . $row['message'] . "</span>
 </span>
</li>";
```

Comment: I get the following:  `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

Comment: I just changed it

Comment: Thanks @calm, always have trouble with escaping in php.  Will need to work on this.

Comment: No problem. Thank you for writing back.